# Emulator command not found on Mac OS 10.7

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I am trying to build AOSP 4.2.2 on mac 10.7.5 with java 1.6.0_65. I followed the source website and compiled . build/envsetup.sh, lunch full-eng. 
How to launch the build on the emulator? I understand that once the build is done, we should be able to run emulator  which will launch the emulator. But now I when I run emulator command it says

```
emulator: command not found
```

I looked at out/host/darwin-x86/bin and I find emulator binary missing. As android documentation says

```
Symptom: The emulator (any version) built on MacOS 10.7 Lion and/or on XCode 4.x doesn't start.
Cause: Some change in the development environment causes the emulator to be compiled in a way that prevents it from working.
Fix: Use an emulator binary from the SDK, which is built on MacOS 10.6 with XCode 3 and works on MacOS 10.7.
```

Can I port the binary from a build created on 10.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in the Android open source. Once you compile the source code successfully, you can copy the emulator binaries from the older version of Mac running AOSP and compile it. It worked perfectly in my case.